# How to add tons of file with git, not one by one

Tags: git

I just did `$ git status` and got this

```
Untracked files:
(use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

bower_components/ng-cordova-oauth/
bower_components/ngCordova/
node_modules/bower/lib/commands/completion.js
node_modules/bower/node_modules/chalk/node_modules/ansi-styles/ansi-styles.js
node_modules/bower/node_modules/chalk/node_modules/has-color/
node_modules/bower/node_modules/decompress-zip/node_modules/graceful-fs/
node_modules/bower/node_modules/fstream-ignore/node_modules/minimatch/.npmignore
node_modules/bower/node_modules/fstream-ignore/node_modules/minimatch/node_modules/
node_modules/bower/node_modules/fstream-ignore/node_modules/minimatch/test/
node_modules/bower/node_modules/fstream/node_modules/.bin/
node_modules/bower/node_modules/fstream/node_modules/graceful-fs/
node_modules/bower/node_modules/fstream/node_modules/mkdirp/
node_modules/bower/node_modules/glob/.npmignore
node_modules/bower/node_modules/glob/.travis.yml
node_modules/bower/node_modules/glob/examples/
node_modules/bower/node_modules/glob/node_modules/minimatch/.npmignore
node_modules/bower/node_modules/glob/node_modules/minimatch/node_modules/
node_modules/bower/node_modules/glob/node_modules/minimatch/test/
node_modules/bower/node_modules/glob/test/
node_modules/bower/node_modules/inquirer/node_modules/async/
node_modules/bower/node_modules/inquirer/node_modules/cli-color/LICENCE
node_modules/bower/node_modules/inquirer/node_modules/cli-color/Makefile
node_modules/bower/node_modules/inquirer/node_modules/cli-color/lib/
node_modules/bower/node_modules/inquirer/node_modules/cli-color/node_modules/es5-ext/LICENCE
node_modules/bower/node_modules/inquirer/node_modules/cli-color/node_modules/es5-ext/Makefile
node_modules/bower/node_modules/inquirer/node_modules/cli-color/node_modules/es5-ext/lib/
node_modules/bower/node_modules/inquirer/node_modules/cli-color/node_modules/es5-ext/test/Array/from.js
node_modules/bower/node_modules/inquirer/node_modules/cli-color/node_modules/es5-ext/test/Array/of.js
node_modules/bower/node_modules/inquirer/node_modules/cli-color/node_modules/es5-ext/test/Array/prototype/
node_modules/bower/node_modules/inquirer/node_modules/cli-color/node_modules/es5-ext/test/Date/prototype/
node_modules/bower/node_modules/inquirer/node_modules/cli-color/node_modules/es5-ext/test/Error/prototype/
node_modules/bower/node_modules/inquirer/node_modules/cli-color/node_modules/es5-ext/test/Function/i.js
node_modules/bower/node_modules/inquirer/node_modules/cli-color/node_modules/es5-ext/test/Function/insert.js
node_modules/bower/node_modules/inquirer/node_modules/cli-color/node_modules/es5-ext/test/Function/k.js
node_modules/bower/node_modules/inquirer/node_modules/cli-color/node_modules/es5-ext/test/Function/prototype/
node_modules/bower/node_modules/inquirer/node_modules/cli-color/node_modules/es5-ext/test/Function/remove.js
node_modules/bower/node_modules/inquirer/node_modules/cli-color/node_modules/es5-ext/test/Math/
node_modules/bower/node_modules/inquirer/node_modules/cli-color/node_modules/es5-ext/test/Number/index.js
node_modules/bower/node_modules/inquirer/node_modules/cli-color/node_modules/es5-ext/test/Number/is-nan.js
node_modules/bower/node_modules/inquirer/node_modules/cli-color/node_modules/es5-ext/test/Number/prototype/
node_modules/bower/node_modules/inquirer/node_modules/cli-color/node_modules/es5-ext/test/Number/to-int.js
node_modules/bower/node_modules/inquirer/node_modules/cli-color/node_modules/es5-ext/test/Number/to-uint.js
node_modules/bower/node_modules/inquirer/node_modules/cli-color/node_modules/es5-ext/test/Object/descriptor.js
node_modules/bower/node_modules/inquirer/node_modules/cli-color/node_modules/es5-ext/test/Object/diff.js
node_modules/bower/node_modules/inquirer/node_modules/cli-color/node_modules/es5-ext/test/Object/extend-deep.js
node_modules/bower/node_modules/inquirer/node_modules/cli-color/node_modules/es5-ext/test/Object/extend-properties.js
node_modules/bower/node_modules/inquirer/node_modules/cli-color/node_modules/es5-ext/test/Object/extend.js
node_modules/bower/node_modules/inquirer/node_modules/cli-color/node_modules/es5-ext/test/Object/is-list.js
node_modules/bower/node_modules/inquirer/node_modules/cli-color/node_modules/es5-ext/test/Object/map-to-array.js
node_modules/bower/node_modules/inquirer/node_modules/cli-color/node_modules/es5-ext/test/Object/reduce.js
node_modules/bower/node_modules/inquirer/node_modules/cli-color/node_modules/es5-ext/test/Object/to-plain-object.js
node_modules/bower/node_modules/inquirer/node_modules/cli-color/node_modules/es5-ext/test/Object/values.js
node_modules/bower/node_modules/inquirer/node_modules/cli-color/node_modules/es5-ext/test/RegExp/
node_modules/bower/node_modules/inquirer/node_modules/cli-color/node_modules/es5-ext/test/String/prototype/
node_modules/bower/node_modules/inquirer/node_modules/cli-color/node_modules/es5-ext/test/reserved.js
node_modules/bower/node_modules/inquirer/node_modules/cli-color/node_modules/memoizee/Makefile
node_modules/bower/node_modules/inquirer/node_modules/cli-color/node_modules/memoizee/lib/
node_modules/bower/node_modules/inquirer/node_modules/cli-color/node_modules/memoizee/node_modules/event-emitter/LICENCE
node_modules/bower/node_modules/inquirer/node_modules/cli-color/node_modules/memoizee/node_modules/event-emitter/Makefile
node_modules/bower/node_modules/inquirer/node_modules/cli-color/node_modules/memoizee/node_modules/event-emitter/lib/
node_modules/bower/node_modules/inquirer/node_modules/cli-color/node_modules/memoizee/node_modules/event-emitter/test/_id.js
node_modules/bower/node_modules/inquirer/node_modules/cli-color/node_modules/memoizee/node_modules/event-emitter/test/core.js
node_modules/bower/node_modules/inquirer/node_modules/cli-color/node_modules/memoizee/node_modules/next-tick/Makefile
node_modules/bower/node_modules/inquirer/node_modules/cli-color/node_modules/memoizee/node_modules/next-tick/lib/
node_modules/bower/node_modules/inquirer/node_modules/cli-color/node_modules/memoizee/node_modules/next-tick/test/
node_modules/bower/node_modules/inquirer/node_modules/cli-color/node_modules/memoizee/test/_base.js
node_modules/bower/node_modules/inquirer/node_modules/cli-color/node_modules/memoizee/test/ext/method.js
node_modules/bower/node_modules/inquirer/node_modules/cli-color/node_modules/memoizee/test/ext/profile.js
node_modules/bower/node_modules/inquirer/node_modules/cli-color/node_modules/memoizee/test/ext/resolvers.js
node_modules/bower/node_modules/inquirer/node_modules/cli-color/node_modules/memoizee/test/primitive.js
node_modules/bower/node_modules/inquirer/node_modules/cli-color/node_modules/memoizee/test/regular.js
node_modules/bower/node_modules/inquirer/node_modules/cli-color/test/_xterm-colors.js
node_modules/bower/node_modules/inquirer/node_modules/cli-color/test/_xterm-match.js
node_modules/bower/node_modules/inquirer/node_modules/readline2/node_modules/strip-ansi/node_modules/
node_modules/bower/node_modules/insight/contributing.md
node_modules/bower/node_modules/insight/lib/insight.js
node_modules/bower/node_modules/insight/node_modules/configstore/
node_modules/bower/node_modules/insight/node_modules/lodash.debounce/node_modules/
node_modules/bower/node_modules/insight/node_modules/object-assign/object-assign.js
node_modules/bower/node_modules/insight/node_modules/request/
node_modules/bower/node_modules/lockfile/bar
node_modules/bower/node_modules/lockfile/foo
node_modules/bower/node_modules/mout/object/deepEquals.js
node_modules/bower/node_modules/mout/src/object/deepEquals.js
node_modules/bower/node_modules/osenv/
node_modules/bower/node_modules/promptly/.editorconfig
node_modules/bower/node_modules/q/CONTRIBUTING.md
node_modules/bower/node_modules/q/benchmark/
node_modules/bower/node_modules/request/dns-request.js
node_modules/bower/node_modules/request/lib/debug.js
node_modules/bower/node_modules/request/lib/getSafe.js
node_modules/bower/node_modules/request/lib/optional.js
node_modules/bower/node_modules/request/node_modules/form-data/node_modules/combined-stream/
node_modules/bower/node_modules/request/node_modules/hawk/node_modules/boom/Makefile
node_modules/bower/node_modules/request/node_modules/mime/
node_modules/bower/node_modules/request/node_modules/qs/.gitmodules
node_modules/bower/node_modules/rimraf/AUTHORS
node_modules/bower/node_modules/rimraf/test/
node_modules/bower/node_modules/stringify-object/stringify-object.js
node_modules/bower/node_modules/tar/
node_modules/bower/node_modules/tmp/LICENSE
node_modules/bower/node_modules/tmp/test/dir-sync-test.js
node_modules/bower/node_modules/tmp/test/file-sync-test.js
node_modules/bower/node_modules/tmp/test/graceful-sync.js
node_modules/bower/node_modules/tmp/test/keep-sync.js
node_modules/bower/node_modules/tmp/test/spawn-sync.js
node_modules/bower/node_modules/tmp/test/unsafe-sync.js
node_modules/bower/node_modules/update-notifier/contributing.md
node_modules/bower/node_modules/update-notifier/lib/
node_modules/bower/node_modules/update-notifier/node_modules/
node_modules/bower/templates/std/update-notice.std
node_modules/gulp-concat/.npmignore
node_modules/gulp-concat/.travis.yml
node_modules/gulp-concat/node_modules/
node_modules/gulp-concat/test/
node_modules/gulp-minify-css/node_modules/clean-css/lib/colors/
node_modules/gulp-minify-css/node_modules/clean-css/lib/properties/shorthand-notations.js
node_modules/gulp-minify-css/node_modules/clean-css/lib/selectors/empty-removal.js
node_modules/gulp-minify-css/node_modules/clean-css/lib/text/comments.js
node_modules/gulp-minify-css/node_modules/clean-css/lib/text/expressions.js
node_modules/gulp-minify-css/node_modules/clean-css/lib/text/free.js
node_modules/gulp-minify-css/node_modules/clean-css/lib/text/urls.js
node_modules/gulp-minify-css/node_modules/clean-css/node_modules/commander/History.md
node_modules/gulp-minify-css/node_modules/clone/
node_modules/gulp-minify-css/node_modules/event-stream/
node_modules/gulp-rename/.editorconfig
node_modules/gulp-rename/.gitattributes
node_modules/gulp-rename/.jshintrc
node_modules/gulp-rename/.npmignore
node_modules/gulp-rename/.travis.yml
node_modules/gulp-rename/Gulpfile.js
node_modules/gulp-rename/LICENSE
node_modules/gulp-rename/test/
node_modules/gulp-sass/
node_modules/gulp-util/node_modules/chalk/node_modules/ansi-styles/ansi-styles.js
node_modules/gulp-util/node_modules/chalk/node_modules/has-color/
node_modules/gulp-util/node_modules/through2/node_modules/xtend/has-keys.js
node_modules/gulp-util/node_modules/through2/node_modules/xtend/node_modules/
node_modules/gulp-util/test/
node_modules/gulp/node_modules/chalk/node_modules/ansi-styles/ansi-styles.js
node_modules/gulp/node_modules/chalk/node_modules/has-color/
node_modules/gulp/node_modules/liftoff/lib/valid_extensions.js
node_modules/gulp/node_modules/liftoff/node_modules/findup-sync/.jshintrc
node_modules/gulp/node_modules/liftoff/node_modules/findup-sync/.travis.yml
node_modules/gulp/node_modules/liftoff/node_modules/findup-sync/Gruntfile.js
node_modules/gulp/node_modules/liftoff/node_modules/findup-sync/node_modules/glob/.npmignore
node_modules/gulp/node_modules/liftoff/node_modules/findup-sync/node_modules/glob/.travis.yml
node_modules/gulp/node_modules/liftoff/node_modules/findup-sync/node_modules/glob/examples/
node_modules/gulp/node_modules/liftoff/node_modules/findup-sync/node_modules/glob/node_modules/minimatch/.npmignore
node_modules/gulp/node_modules/liftoff/node_modules/findup-sync/node_modules/glob/node_modules/minimatch/node_modules/
node_modules/gulp/node_modules/liftoff/node_modules/findup-sync/node_modules/glob/node_modules/minimatch/test/
node_modules/gulp/node_modules/liftoff/node_modules/findup-sync/node_modules/glob/test/
node_modules/gulp/node_modules/liftoff/node_modules/findup-sync/node_modules/lodash/
node_modules/gulp/node_modules/liftoff/node_modules/findup-sync/test/
node_modules/gulp/node_modules/liftoff/node_modules/minimist/
node_modules/gulp/node_modules/semver/foot.js
node_modules/gulp/node_modules/semver/head.js
node_modules/gulp/node_modules/vinyl-fs/.npmignore
node_modules/gulp/node_modules/vinyl-fs/.travis.yml
node_modules/gulp/node_modules/vinyl-fs/lib/dest/writeBuffer.js
node_modules/gulp/node_modules/vinyl-fs/lib/dest/writeContents.js
node_modules/gulp/node_modules/vinyl-fs/lib/dest/writeDir.js
node_modules/gulp/node_modules/vinyl-fs/lib/dest/writeStream.js
node_modules/gulp/node_modules/vinyl-fs/lib/src/bufferFile.js
node_modules/gulp/node_modules/vinyl-fs/lib/src/getContents.js
node_modules/gulp/node_modules/vinyl-fs/lib/src/readDir.js
node_modules/gulp/node_modules/vinyl-fs/lib/src/streamFile.js
node_modules/gulp/node_modules/vinyl-fs/node_modules/glob-stream/node_modules/through2/
node_modules/gulp/node_modules/vinyl-fs/node_modules/map-stream/
node_modules/gulp/node_modules/vinyl-fs/node_modules/vinyl/.npmignore
node_modules/gulp/node_modules/vinyl-fs/node_modules/vinyl/.travis.yml
node_modules/gulp/node_modules/vinyl-fs/node_modules/vinyl/test/
node_modules/gulp/node_modules/vinyl-fs/test/
platforms/ios/UrbanetApp/Plugins/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/
platforms/ios/www/img/3004.jpg
platforms/ios/www/plugins/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/
plugins/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/
www/img/jarra.jpg
www/img/picnic.jpg
www/img/ur.jpg
www/img/vertigo.jpg
www/js/controllers/NewsCtrl.js
www/js/controllers/PromoDetailCtrl.js
www/js/services/PromoFactory.js
www/templates/tab-promo-detail.html
www/templates/tab-promotions.html

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
MacBook-Pro-de-MarceloRS:urbanet Marcelo$
```

I don't know what is going here, but, how can I add those files all together ?

Comment: By adding the folder that contains the files.

Comment: you can just `git add .`. those files are created while installing the bower dependencies

Answer (score 3):

You should not add them! most of them were installed using `bower` and `npm` and should not be checked into VCS. Instead, add them to the `.gitignore` file:

```
node_modules
bower_components
platforms
plugins
```

After that you should see less *untracked files* and can add them using

```
git add .
```

Comment: just add it to the .gitignore file, but still the same in git status

Comment: should I add those files in the git page or from my project in Sublime?

Comment: I don't understand your question, sorry.

Comment: Sorry, I added those 2 lines to .gitignore, but I am still getting the same when I do ```git status```

Comment: Yes, I understood that but don't know what might be the reason for this. Are you certain `.gitignore` is located in the root of your repo? Are you certain the content of the file is correct?

Comment: yes, .gitignore is in the root of my repo, and all I have in that file are those 2 lines ```npm_modules``` and ```bower_components```

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to add those files, you could do

```
git add .
```

However, chances are you don't want to add all,those files, because you don't need to distribute them with your project (since those files are in general installed by npm). So instead of doing this, you might rather want to add in your `.gitignore` file the lines

```
node_modules
bower_components
```

so that the output of `git status` won't be polluted by those files anymore

Comment: just add it to the .gitignore file, but still the same in git status

Comment: should I add those files in the git page or from my project in Sublime?

Answer (score 1):

First create a `.gitignore` file and set `bower_components`and `node_modules` in this file, because you should not add this directories to git ([npm documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/faq#should-i-check-my-node_modules-folder-into-git), [gitignore documentation](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore)).

Then add the directory you want to add to your commit :
`git add .gitignore www ...`

Comment: there is already a file with the name ```.gitignore```, so I added ```bower_components``` and ```node_modules``` to it, but I am getting the same when I do ```git status```

Comment: Is you `.gitignore` file at your project's root ? Could you show us the content of this file ?

Comment: the content of my file .gitignore is just only those 2 lines, bower_components and node_modules, http://prntscr.com/6vr6fl

Comment: Ok, so just try to add a `/` after each lines like `node_modules/`